# C++ using float numbers, functions not calculating valid data

Tags: c++, floating-point

Writing a class rectangle for this assignment Create a class Rectangle with attributes length and width, each of which defaults to 1. Provide member functions that calculate the perimeter and the area of the rectangle. Also, provide set and get functions for the length and width attributes. The set functions should verify that length and width are each floating-point numbers larger than 0.0 and less than 20.0.;

The code executes, but the output is incorrect. The functions must not be calling correctly.

example of output

```
>The first objects information is
>the length is 1 
>the width is 1
>the perimeter is -1.07374e+08 the area is -1.07374e+08 
>The second objects information is   
>the length is -1.07374e+08
>the width is -1.07374e+08 
>the perimeter is -1.07374e+08 
>the area is -1.07374e+08
```

Header file

```
#ifndef Rectangle_H
#define Rectangle_H
class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle();
    Rectangle(float length);
    Rectangle(float length, float width);
    ~Rectangle();
    float setLengthAndWidth(float, float);
    float setLength(float Length);
    float setWidth(float Width);
    float calculatePerimeter();
    float calculateArea();
    void printInfo();
    float getLength();
    float getWidth();
private:
    float length;
    float width;
    float area;
    float perimeter;
};
#endif#pragma once
```

main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include "Rectangle.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Rectangle objectOne;
    Rectangle objectTwo(7.1, 3.2);
    Rectangle objectThree(6.3);
    Rectangle objectFour(200, 300);
    Rectangle objectFive = objectTwo;
    cout << "The first objects information is\n  ";
    objectOne.printInfo();
    cout << "The second objects information is\n  ";
    objectTwo.printInfo();
    cout << "The third objects information is\n  ";
    objectThree.printInfo();
    cout << "The fourth objects information is\n  ";
    objectFour.printInfo();
    cout << "The fifth objects information is\n  ";
    objectFive.printInfo();
}
```

Member .cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include "Rectangle.h"
using namespace std;
Rectangle::Rectangle()
{
    length = width = 1.0;
}
Rectangle::Rectangle(float length)
{
    setLengthAndWidth(length, 1.0);
}
Rectangle::Rectangle(float length, float width)
{
    setLengthAndWidth(length, width);
}
float Rectangle::setLengthAndWidth(float Len, float Wid)
{
    setLength(Len);
    setWidth(Wid);
}
float Rectangle::setLength(float length)
{
    if (length >= 0 || length <= 20.0)
        length = length;
    else
        length = 1.0;
}
float Rectangle::setWidth(float width)
{
    if (width >= 0 || width <= 20.0)
        width = width;
    else
        width = 1.0;
}
float Rectangle::calculatePerimeter()
{
    perimeter = (length * 2) + (width * 2) ;
    return perimeter;
}
float Rectangle::calculateArea()
{
    area = length * width;
    return area;
}
float Rectangle::getLength()
{
    cout << "Please enter length" << endl;
    cin >> length;
        return length;
}
float Rectangle::getWidth()
{
    cout << "Please enter width" << endl;
    cin >> width;
    return width;
}

void Rectangle::printInfo()
{
    cout << "the length is " << length << endl << "the width is " << width << endl;
    cout << "the perimeter is " << perimeter << endl << "the area is " << area << endl;

}
Rectangle::~Rectangle()
{
    cout << "the object has gone out of scope. ";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `setLength()` member doesn't set `this->length`, and similarly for `setWidth()`. All they do is set the parameter, which has no permanent effect.

Comment: Ok. Any guidance on how to correct? I'm lost as to how to correct it.

Comment: Because a local variable named `length` is defined in `setLength()` (in this case the input argument), the class member variable named `length` is not directly accessible anymore. This is called "variable shadowing" or just shadowing. To avoid confusion I recommend renaming the local variable to something other than `length`. Ex: change declaration to `float Rectangle::setLength(float len)` then change `if (length >= 0 || length <= 20.0)` to `if (len >= 0 || len <= 20.0)` and `length = length` to `length = len`. Alternatively, you could just change `length = length` to `this->length = length`.

Comment: The 'guidance' is to *set* `this->length`, instead of the parameter, and similarly for `this->width`. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: Personally I try to avoid all situations where one name hides another. In this case I would do something like name the members with an "m_" prefix, or else add a "_" suffix to the function arguments.